# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I was using the Visual Studio Profiler on my web application when at some point while it was running Visual Studio crashed. Now everytime I try to run my web application I get this exception in the web browser:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but did not correct the error:

- restored the original web.config (removing all the profiler additions that were automatically added)
- deleted all binaries and source, pulled all code fresh, and rebuilt the entire web application
- deleted the web application entry in iis
- deleted all files in \WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

I must be missing something small somewhere. It is as if there is still a binary that is still instrumented somewhere or something and is referencing ASPNetHelper. I don't know.

I'm using: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

Any thoughts on what else I could try? Thanks!

Comment: Version? sp? web site or web app?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Web Application

Comment: @John Saunders: 'ASPNetHelper' Obvious it's a web app ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it! There was a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper` in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`. As soon as I removed that, it worked! Since I never work out of that folder, I never thought to look there.

Answer (score 10):

To expand upon Jon's answer:

The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper' library is used with Visual Studio Profiling:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255412.aspx .

If you are no longer using profiling or do not have a version of Visual Studio that is using the Visual Studio Profiling tool this may be why it throws an error.  In my case, I had a different version of Visual Studio than my co-worker.

Re-moving reference in the web.config resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this problem by adding that file to the GAC on my build controller.  It's located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools.

Comment: This worked for me except that the folder I copied from was:


`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`

Comment: This worked for me as well.  For me the assembly was in PrivateAssemblies, as it was for Josh.  To add to the gac, gacutil -i \path\to\assembly

Comment: This started occurring after removing Visual Studio 2013. Using gacutil on the current version fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I googled and I found this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/56dd11d1-d920-4fd1-939b-2c65d264b250

It says:
'
When we build with code coverage enabled, VS makes some changes to the config file and the same will be restored back once the build is over. If its MSBuild(IDE), VS will tell you that the config file got modified outside VS two times. I observed that the above error occures when there is only one such notification - means when VS fails to restore the config file. I restored the config file using the backup copy and its started working fine. :)
'

Comment: I found that too. It mentions web.config changes and copying Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper.dll to the correct location (via a link). Both I have looked at and tried, but it still didn't correct my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an error that is shown in web broweser window, this means that assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper is not being copied to output directory.

Go to solution explorer, find References, and click on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.ASPNetHelper, Properties, and set Copy option (do not remeber exact name of this option) to copy an assembly.

Comment: That is what it sounds like, but none of my projects (I search just to make sure) do not reference ASPNetHelper. From what I understand that reference is added when the assemblies are instrumented for profiling. I'm trying to remove all profiling references. I must have missed one somewhere, but don't know where to look.

Comment: Did that. I checked all the files I could think of (*.config;*.vbproj;*.sln;*.csproj). Those are the only places I know to check.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens while you are working on your Visual Studio, you may want to close it and reopen it.  It has happened to me several times, especially when I have multiple VS open, and closing and re opening it do the magic